# Production APS support to MAC Application distributed outside of the AppStore (Developer ID Application certificate signed)

Tags: macos

What is the min OS X version from which  MAC Application distributed outside of the AppStore (Signed using Developer ID application certificate, Developer ID Installer certificate ) can receive the Apple production environment push notifications (Remote notifications) ?

Able to receive the notifications on Sierra and El Capitan but failing with Yosemite version.